# How to trace a users path on a map?

Tags: rubymotion

I am developing an iOS app using Rubymotion.
In this app I want to be able to show the user on a map exactly which way he or she have driven or walked. I also want to save this path on the server.

How can I trace this patch in iOS?

All input and hints about a solution is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

i guess your app needs a timer:

```
count = 0
timer = EM.add_periodic_timer 1.0 do
  count = count + 1
  puts "Great scott!"
  (count < 10) || EM.cancel_timer(timer)
end
```

and then find the current location:

```
BW::Location.get do |result|
  p "From Lat #{result[:from].latitude}, Long #{result[:from].longitude}"
  p "To Lat #{result[:to].latitude}, Long #{result[:to].longitude}"
end
```

all this is BubbleWrap: https://github.com/rubymotion/BubbleWrap

Comment: Looks interesting. How should I use them together? What do I use the timer for?

Comment: sorry, you have to do the thinking part yourself